# Is there an HTTP server for Chapel?

Tags: chapel

A little background: I would like to build my API in Chapel as a docker container on Azure (or AppEngine) using a Crate.io database and ODBC drivers.

Is there an HTTP server I can use with Chapel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no official HTTP server support in Chapel, but the Chapel
team does plan to work on this in the future.

The project "Write a web server in Chapel" is listed as a suggested
project idea on [Chapel's Google Summer of Code (GSoC) page](http://chapel.cray.com/gsoc/ideas.html#demos). For [GSoC 2016](https://summerofcode.withgoogle.com/organizations/6608321708556288/), Chapel had several applicants for this specific project, one of
which even coded up a toy web server in Chapel. However, this project was not
selected for GSoC 2016.

Hopefully this is a project that will get more attention in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

We are working in an  simple http server (based on libevent2) at https://github.com/marcoscleison/chapel-http .
The project is in inital commits but you can see and have an idea how to create an http server.

Answer (score 1):

One more note - see https://github.com/briangu/chearch/ for an example program that rolls its own server in Chapel. Also, note that ZeroMQ support is in progress in this pull request: https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/pull/3592. Hopefully you can find alternative solutions from one of those resources, although I don't think there's really anything wrong with using stdout and CGI.